# Inexplicable problems with sculpting "Draw" tool

Tags: texturing, sculpting, sculpt-mode, brushes

all!

I've been having a lot of trouble with the "draw" tool lately, which I use frequently to add texture to objects. I can't figure out what I have done wrong or how to fix it, and I wonder if my issue may be a bit too niche for an easy answer? Regardless, I'm hoping for some advice on the matter. The main issue - from what I can diagnose - is that my texture image/file isn't loading in properly. That is, when I press "F" to check the scale of my texture brush, no brush is shown. Regardless of what I do no texture is applied to the object. This issue is a first for me!

So far I have: Toggled Dynotopo off then on again (It's always on,) Toggled "Front faces only" off then on again, uninstalled and reinstalled blender, attempted to change the "texture" setting, remeshed the object, sent the object to another program in case it needed repairs (it did not), recalculated the normals, and tried every texture brush I have. The object has around 80k faces and my computer has no issue calculating texture changes, I have built it specifically for this purpose.